# Calling Shell Script from xquery module in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Is there any direct way to execute shell scripts or linux commands from xquery in MarkLogic? Does Marklogic web server supports CGI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, you can't execute shell scripts or file system executables from MarkLogic nor does MarkLogic support CGI.  The easiest path to such integration is to stand up a copy of an app server you are comfortable with (Java/Tomcat, ASP, PHP, and so on) and communicate between MarkLogic and that service over http.

There is an open enhancement request to support executing file system executables.

Comment: Earlier I have used MLJAM to call java code and then execute shell script from java program but it will be good if there is some ML extension API to directly accomplish this.